# I need assistance creating a SQL Oracle running in Oracle Database to fetch only those columns which has NO NUMERIC VALUES

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried with this method:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column1 not like '%[^0-9]%' and column1 != ''
```

but nothing really is happening, I need to filter a column which has purely no numeric values in it.

Comment: What does "*Nothing is really happening*" mean?  Be specific.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? You could use the REGEXP_LIKE condition: [https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php]

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
column1 not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Does not do what you think.  It matches strings that look like:

```
 abasdfs[^0-9]asfsdf
 ^-----^ any string
        ^----^ exactly this
              ^-----^ any string
```

Presumably, you want a string that only contains digits.  I would suggest one of:

```
regexp_like(column1, '^[0-9]*$')
not regexp_like(column1, '[^0-9]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want *numbers* only (not necessarily the same as numeric values), you could also use the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` function. That returns 1 if conversion to a datatype is successful. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

```
SELECT column1 
  FROM table 
 WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(column1 AS NUMBER) = 1
```

example:

```
sql>create table test_table(column1 VARCHAR2(10));

Table TEST_TABLE created.

sql>INSERT INTO test_table (column1) VALUES (100);

1 row inserted.

sql>INSERT INTO test_table (column1) VALUES ('TEXT');

1 row inserted.

sql>SELECT column1 
  2    FROM test_table 
  3*  WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(column1 AS NUMBER) = 1;

COLUMN1   
----------
100
```